# Select dynamic button robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm automating a test case in the robot framework.

I have a problem, when I have to select a button that does not always have the same xpath. This is because it depends on a growing list, and each row of the list has an associated button.

Example button xpath:

```
xpath = //*[@id="tab_student"]/ul[1]/li[4]/div/div/div[3]/a

xpath = //*[@id="tab_student"]/ul[1]/li[5]/div/div/div[3]/a

xpath = //*[@id="tab_student"]/ul[1]/li[6]/div/div/div[3]/a
```

If the list increases or decreases, the button will be in different xpath.

How can I find the button I want from the list row?

I attached the html code to the button:

< a data-bind="attr: { title: $root.i18n.t('text_access_content'), href: '/#/ce-student?Subject='+ $root.page.getParam('SubjectID') + '&CourseID=' + $root.page.getParam('CourseID') + '&' + (unit_origin == 'U' ? 'UnitID' : 'MyUnitID') + '=' + unit_id+ '&Dash=' + unit_identifier }, text: $root.i18n.t('text_open')" class="b-see-unit" href="/#/notebook-stuendt?SubjectID=51&CourseID=6&Un‌​itID=655&Dash=EN‌​_3C_00" title="Access Unit" >Open< /a>

Thank you.

Comment: How do you know which button you want? What's the criteria?

Comment: Hi Bryan, because before I created an item in the list. This new item in the list has a button associated with it that is what I need to press.

Comment: Does that mean you always want the last item in the list?

Comment: No, that is the problem. The list is variable, that is, you can delete or add elements. I want to click on the element I just created that has a title: day and hour / minute / second.

Comment: I suppose if there's no way to know which one was just created, you can get a list of all of the existing ones, create the new one, then compare the list to find the one that is new.

Comment: But how do I get the element xpath?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163655/discussion-between-marta79-and-bryan-oakley).

Comment: @Marta79 can you provide the html code for the button? Although the xpath you created works, it may not be the most efficient or effective way of writing it.

Comment: @A.Kootstra I attached the html code to the button:


<a data-bind="attr: { title: $root.i18n.t('text_access_content'), href: '/#/ce-student?Subject='+ $root.page.getParam('SubjectID') + '&amp;CourseID=' + $root.page.getParam('CourseID') + '&amp;' + (unit_origin == 'U' ? 'UnitID' : 'MyUnitID') + '=' + unit_id+ '&amp;Dash=' + unit_identifier }, text: $root.i18n.t('text_open')" class="b-see-unit" href="/#/notebook-stuendt?SubjectID=51&amp;CourseID=6&amp;UnitID=655&amp;Dash=EN_3C_00" title="Access Unit">Open</a>

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the above code as a code block. This helps with the readability of the code itself as comments don't allow for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that the code example provided in the comments doesn't come from the actual source code of the browser, it does provide enough information to craft a better xpath.

`//*[@id="tab_student"]//a[@title='Access Unit' and @class='b-see-unit' and text()='Open']`

In this case the first part of your xpath (`//*[@id="tab_student"]`) is retained. The double slash `//` can be repeatedly used to 'skip' parts of the DOM.

We then proceed to create an AND construction where the element needs to have two specific attributes (`title` and `class`) with each a specific value. In addition to this the visible link text should be 'Open'.

The [W3schools xpath tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) is good place to start if you want to know more about xpath.